# Unable to capture video file in Emgu

Tags: c#, video, emgucv, capture

I am trying to create simple application using emgu cv 3.1.0.2282 for reading video file. I used following code to capture video from file. Capturing from webcam works fine.

```
Capture _capture = new Capture("D:\\test.avi");
```

after this code is executed, the _capture variable will be assigned with some value (not null), but the height and width properties is 0.
But when I use that code in Emgu.CV.Example project, it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've already know the problem. the video can't be loaded because there's no opencv_ffmpeg310.dll library. the solution is just copy opencv_ffmpeg310.dll in bin folder